# Drag and drop predefined object into document viewer

Tags: angular, pdf-viewer

I would like to make an angular page that will do the following:

1. allow user to upload a document (not an issue)
2. display the content of the document
3. allow the user to drag a predefined object into the document display section to specify the location at which they will sign for example.
4. a button when clicked, it will retrieve the coordinates of the predefined object with respect to the document location. so that no matter how big the screen is or how small it is, it will always give the same coordinate if located at the same location with respect to the document.

I don't need a full solution. I need someone to point me at the right direction. I tried to search online but i didn't get anything. maybe i am using wrong terminology.

for now, the document type will be either word or pdf. it would be great if someone can suggest a library.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: "I don't need a full solution. I need someone to point me at the right direction." about which problem ? 2, 3 and 4 ? Can you make the question more focused ?

Comment: @Elikill58 2,3, and 4. the only thing that is simple to me is the first 1. I can't focus on point 2 without 3 as point 3 depends on point 2. so I need to solve point 2 in a way that will enable me to solve point 3 without any concern or change my solution to point 2. the same for point 4. I apologies if it is still unclear to you

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this task a simple one is using ngx-dropzone pkg.

`npm install --save ngx-dropzone`

Here are the details https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/drag-and-drop-image-upload-in-angular-exampleexample.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your effort. However, that is not what I am looking for. I don't need a dropzone to drop my file from my desktop for example. I need to upload a pdf document for example in a normal way from a button. Then will display the document to the user using a pdf viewer. then I will drag and drop a predefined <div> element into the pdf viewer. Then I need to get the coordinates of that <div> element in respect to the document.